# Querying SQL Server xml column with user provided XPath via Entity Framework

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, xpath

I'm having a really tough time figuring how to use an xml data column in SQL Server, specifically for use with Entity Framework.

Basically, one of our tables stores "custom metadata" provided by users in the form of XML, so it seemed sensible to store this in an Xml column in the table.

One of the requirements of our application is to support searching of the metadata, however.  The users are able to provided an XPath query string, as well as a value to compare the value of the XPath with, to search for elements that contain metadata that matches their query.

I identified the SQL Server xml functions as ideal for this (eg, [xmlcol].exist('/path1/path2[0][text()=''valuetest'''] ), but they're not supported by Entity Framework, irritatingly (or specifically, xml columns aren't supported).  As an alternative, I tried creating a UDF that passes the user-provided XPath to the xml functions, but then discovered that the xml functions only allow string literals, so I can't provide variables...

At this point, I was running out of options.

I created a small bit of code that performs a regular expression replace on the result of a IQueryable.ToString(), to inject my XPath filter in, and then send this string to the database manually, but there are problems with this too, such as the result doesn't seem to lazily load the navigational properties, for example.

I kept looking, and stumbled upon the idea of SQLCLR types, and started creating a SQLCLR function that performs the XPath comparison.  I thought I was onto a winner at this point, until a colleague pointed out that SQL Server in Azure doesn't support SQLCLR - doh!

What other options do I have? I seem to be running very close to empty...

Answer (score 2):

You could do this in a stored procedure where you build your query dynamically.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4e6f9/2)

**MS SQL Server 2008 Schema Setup**:

```
create table YourTable
(
  ID int identity primary key,
  Name varchar(10) not null,
  XMLCol xml
);

go

insert into YourTable values
('Row 1', '<x>1</x>'),
('Row 2', '<x>2</x>'),
('Row 3', '<x>3</x>');

go

create procedure GetIt
  @XPath nvarchar(100)
as
begin
  declare @SQL nvarchar(max);

  set @SQL = N'
  select ID, Name
  from YourTable
  where XMLCol.exist('+quotename(@XPath, '''')+N') = 1';

  exec (@SQL);
end
```

**Query 1**:

```
exec GetIt N'*[text() = "2"]'
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4e6f9/2/0)**:

```
| ID |  NAME |
--------------
|  2 | Row 2 |
```

Comment: I had considered this to be honest, but there is so much about the search results that need to be customisable (orderby column, number of results, offset of the result set) that it seems much easier to build up the query in linq, if at all possible.

Comment: However, +1 for that SQL Fiddle link - I've not seen that before, but it looks handy!

Comment: Dynamic SQL is the answer to dynamic query building. If you want to specify number of results you can dynamically embed a ` + ' TOP ' + @results + ' ' + ` into the building of your SQL statement to be executed. Order by in the same way. I usually add a ` WHERE 1 = 1 ` to handle default where criteria and allow you to add none or as many criteria as you want to cull down the data. I second the going of this route.

Comment: This is one giant security hole.

Comment: @flup would you care to explain a bit about what you mean? If you are referring to sql-injection it would be interesting to see if you could provide a XPath that does that.

Comment: An XPath that gets properly terminated and then continues to drop tables. But aside from that, the user has no business providing something so low level as XPath expressions to your database.

Comment: @flup I don't think you can do that here. Please provide the expression that does that.

Comment: I'll take it one notch back and call it one hell of a security risk instead.

Comment: @flup and I will stop pestering you with an expression and instead tell you that it is `quotename` that takes care of protecting this from an injection attack. Is it safe? Well, I don't know of a way to hack this and [smarter people than me says the same](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html#quotestring). It would be really interesting if you/someone actually could provide something that injects when `quotename` is used.

Comment: What triggered me was the ease with which more parameters already got added. Muck up the parsing of the `@results` parameter and things will break. Also, you'd be letting the user provide both the document and the XPath expression. A DDOS attack should be relatively easy for users to conjure up. A blind XPath explorer can [figure out the full metadata document](http://code.google.com/p/xpath-blind-explorer/). The SQL Server uses XQuery 1.0, not 2.0. So it won't let you refer to external documents (yet?). But the other columns of the row that contains the document are queryable too.

Comment: @MikaelEriksson If pressed for an expression, I'd stammer that `quotename` can overflow. Maybe.

Comment: The user should already know the full metadata document, as they provided the document in the first place, so not too worried about this.

Comment: @dark_perfect depending on the query plan, this might include rows the user did not add, himself. I'd recommend you provide a simple subset of expressions that the user may use to query the metadata.

Answer (score 0):

To remain "customisable", the [SqlQuery method on DbSet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj592907.aspx) can be used:

```
var query = @"SET ARITHABORT ON; 
              select * from [YourTable] where 
              [xmlcol].exist('/path1/path2[0][text()=''{0}''']";
var numOfResults = 5;
var offsetPage = 1;

var results = Context.YourTable.SqlQuery(String.Format(query,"valuetest"))
                              .OrderBy(x => x.col)
                              .Skip(offsetPage * numOfResults)
                              .Take(numOfResults).ToList();
```

Note, due to its dynamic nature, this method would also most likely expose some degree of sql injection security holes.

Comment: Does this execute the query, and then apply the order, skip and take locally?  I'm going to test this, and if it works, I'm going to accept this as the answer.